# Understanding file locations in python - unexpected errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python 3.3 in windows 7. I have a two text files - lines.txt and raven.txt in a folder. Both contain the same text for the first example.

When I try to access ravens, using the code below, I get the error -

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Python\raven.txt'
```

I know that the above error can be fixed by using an escape character like this -

```
C:\\Python\\raven.txt
C:\Python\\raven.txt
```

Why do both methods work ? Strangely, when I access `lines.txt` in the same folder, I get no error ! Why ?

```
import re

def main():
    print('')
    fh = open('C:\Python\lines.txt')

    for line in fh:
        if re.search('(Len|Neverm)ore', line):
            print(line, end = '')

if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

Also, when I use the line below, I get a completely different error - `TypeError: embedded NUL character`. Why ?

```
fh = open('C:\Python\Exercise Files\09 Regexes\raven.txt')
```

I can rectify this by using `\` before every \ in the file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\r is an escape character, but \l is not. So, lines is interpreted as lines while raven is interpreted as `aven`, since \r is escaped.

```
In [1]: len('\l')
Out[1]: 2
In [2]: len('\r')
Out[2]: 1
```

You should always escape backslashes with `\\`. In cases your string doesn't have quotes, you can also use raw strings:

```
In [9]: len(r'\r')
Out[9]: 2
In [10]: r'\r'
Out[10]: '\\r'
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html

Comment: \r is an escape character, but \l is not. So, lines is interpreted as lines while raven is interpreted as `aven`, since \r is escaped.

Comment: can you tell me the cause for the error `ypeError: embedded NUL character`

Comment: It's because of `\0` sequence in `'C:\Python\Exercise Files\09 Regexes\raven.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

just like this `open(r'C:\Python\Exercise Files\09 Regexes\raven.txt')`.

> When an `r' or`R' prefix is present, backslashes are still used to
>   quote the following character, but all backslashes are left in the
>   string. For example, the string literal r"\n" consists of two
>   characters: a backslash and a lowercase `n'. String quotes can be
>   escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for
>   example, r"\"" is a valid string literal consisting of two characters:
>   a backslash and a double quote; r"\" is not a value string literal
>   (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes).
>   Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the
>   backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that
>   a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two
>   characters as part of the string, not as a line continuation.

Comment: can you tell me the cause for the error `ypeError: embedded NUL character`

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use forward slashes instead of backward ones, that way you don't have to escape them at all, which would save you a lot of headaches. Like this: 'C:/Python/raven.txt', I can guarantee that it works on Windows.